# SQL - Best Way [Opening Closing Balance]

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, database-design

**[EDITED]** I am working on a simple setup of inventory with following tables and columns:

Item Table [Edited]

```
id|title|supplier_id|sku
```

Stock Table [Edited - Main Inventory]

```
id|date|item_id|quantity
```

Stock Received [Received against Purchase Order]

```
id|item_id|qty_received|date| purchaseorder_id
```

Stock Issuance [Issued against Demand Note]

```
id|qty_given|date|demand_id
```

Quantity in *Stock* table will be increased/decreased dependent on *stock issuance* or *stock received* , so the quantity will always be physically accurate.

**[NOTE]** I want to keep my item list totally separate from in/out transactions, so i kept it separate.

"Stock Table" is where i keep the exact quantity of every item.

"Stock Rec" + "Stock Issue" are used to keep track of item in/out transactions, instead of keeping extraneous column of in/out transactions in "stock table" and continuously updating them without a record of when the transactions were made.

My question is, Will i be able to calculate the Opening & Closing balance accurately. on any given dates? using all four of these tables.

Please note, then "Stock Table" holds, around 18000 rows and can grow with a rate of 10-15 per month.

Comment: `mysql` or `sql server`? You want the `quantity` for the lowest & highest timestamp per day from the stock` table?

Comment: doesn't matter. i am not looking for a query, just want to know a table structure "best practice". SQL server will do.

Comment: Seems like the last three tables should really be one.

Comment: You will ALWAYS have ONE stock table for ONE stock received for ONE stock issuance? If yes why you don't make ONE table?

Comment: This is way too vague to give a reasonable response. The columns here so ambiguous. Regardless this is really off topic as being both too broad and primarily opinion based.

Comment: @SeanLange i've edited the question. Nothing vague in it. i just want to keep data seperate and be able to find the relevant data when needed. Relevant columns are mentioned , which basically forms the query in SQL.

Comment: @MickaelLeger There won't be any record of when an in /out transaction was made, so it is good to keep them separate.

Comment: On the contrary it is vague. What does timestamps mean? The formatting here makes it really hard to see what is going on. And since the only question you are asking is if you will be able to get accurate balances on a given date you should be able to answer that. Consider what the query would look like and then look at the table. Does the query make sense? The issue is you are asking if your design is adequate but only providing some of the design.

Comment: I would guess that if the StockTable value is correct then you could take that value and adjust it by any transactions made since the date you are wanting the balance for. Seems a little funky but would work.

Comment: so, if for January, I add all the stock-received and subtract all stock-issuance from the quantity in "Stock table" will give me an exact figure? OK. Good. Thanks

timestamps() are laravel DateTime Stamp

Comment: 18K rows is small; don't worry about performance (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes!**

The structure that you are using is enough and quite efficient as per your requirement. It will definitely be able to provide all necessary details ( as described in OP) for opening and closing balance of given dates.

Use of `joins` will be quite helpful.